# wkhtmltopdf landscape page break

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I have a page that creates a table dynamically.  Sometimes the table can be very wide, but not very tall.  When converting to PDF, I would like it to span multiple pages, instead of shrinking down to fit on a single page, which is what it does now.  When shrunk, it is so small, the text is pretty much unreadable.

So, basically I need to somehow make a 'horizontal' page break if that makes any sense.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `page-break-before:always` style on the elements where you want to start with a new page.